# How to retrieve object from interface collection based on predicate specific to concrete class?

Tags: c#

I have a collection of objects as a property in my class implementing `IFoo`. I'd like to add a method for retrieval of an item from the collection by type and predicate (specific to the concrete implementation). The problem I have is that I can't downcast from collection defined by interface to my concrete class (type cannot be inferred from usage) like so:

```
public HashSet<IFoo> Foos { get; } = new HashSet<IFoo>();

public T GetFoo<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        if (Foos != null && predicate != null)
        {
            var foos = Foos.Where(f => f is T);
            return foo = foos.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `HashSet` is of type `IFoo`, it is expected that your predicate also uses `IFoo`.  The easiest way to accomplish this is to change the signature of your method:

```
    public IFoo GetFoo<T>(Func<IFoo, bool> predicate) where T: IFoo, class
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I'm retrieving IFoo and downcasting in the predicate and other places I actually use it but not on retrieval:

```
 public IFoo GetFoo<T>(Func<IFoo, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        if (Foos != null && predicate != null)
        {
            var foos = Foos.Where(f => f is T);
            return foos.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        }

        return null;
    }
```